# python sum the values of lists of list

Tags: python, list, sum

I have list of lists and i need to sum the inner lists, for example,

```
a = [[1,2,3], [2,1,4], [4,3,6]]
```

for my case, the len of a[i] is same, that is all the inner lists have same dimension.

and i need the output as

```
result = [6,7,13]
```

what i did is:

```
result = [sum(a[i]) for i in range(len(a))]
```

Since my len(a) is very high, i hope there will be a alternative way to get the result without using the for loop.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
result = map(sum, a)
```

Is the way I would do it.  Alternatively:

```
result = [sum(b) for b in a]
```

The second variation is the same as yours, except it avoids the unnecessary range statement.  In Python, you can iterate over lists directly without having to keep a separate variable as an index.

Comment: If you use `map`, you might consider doing `list(map(sum, a))` to ensure a `list` object is the final result.

Comment: map is the fastest solution i think ,,, is there any way map would not result in a list?

Comment: @JoranBeasley Technically if you printed `map(sum, a)` you would get `<map object at -some memory address->`, since the `map object` is what `map()` returns.

Comment: this is what i got in py2.6 `>>> print map(sum,a)
[6, 12]` ... but you may have a point for 3+ but `type(map(sum,a)) == <type 'list'>` at least in python 2.6

Comment: @ktodisco - That's true for Python 3, but not for Python 2.

Comment: I didnt know they had changed it in 3+

Comment: @del I hadn't checked Python 2, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @misha What i can do if i need the result like code`[[6],[7],[13]]

Comment: `result = [[sum(b) for b in a]]`

Comment: if a is array then, the simple way to achieve this is      `result=a.sum(1)`

Answer (score 3):

I know that no one like it but just to give an option:

```
result = [reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, l) for l in a]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer.

```
a = [[1,2,3], [2,1,4], [4,3,6]]
result = [sum(l) for l in a]

result
[6, 7, 13]
```

Comment: You see that `OP` don't want for loop (He meant List Comprehension in fact)