# Sum numbers of each row of a matrix Python

Tags: python, sum

```
lista = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

print(lista)

def filas(lista):

    res=[]
    for elemento in lista:
        x = sum(lista[elemento])
        res.append(x)
    print(res)
```

I need to sum the numbers of each row, and then print it as a list. It seems the problem I have is that I try to sum the sublists, instead of the numbers of each row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python sum the values of lists of list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283689/python-sum-the-values-of-lists-of-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you are having, is that you are already iterating over the elements so it is unnecessary to use it as an index:

```
    x = sum(elemento)
```

It is generally considered bad form but to iterate over indexes you would use:

```
for i in range(len(lista)):
    x = sum(lista[i])
```

However, without introducing any other modules, you can use `map()` or a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> res = list(map(sum, lista))   # You don't need `list()` in Py2
>>> print(res)
[6, 15, 24]
```

Or

```
>>> res = [sum(e) for e in lista]
>>> print(res)
[6, 15, 24]
```

Comment: _"It is generally considered bad form but to iterate over indexes you would use:"_ - Perhaps it would also be a good idea to tell the OP the 'idiomatic' way of looping over a list's indexes. eg. `enumerate()`?

Comment: `enumerate()` is definitely idiomatic if you need the index and the item. but because the OP only needs the item - `for elemento in lista:` is already idiomatic.

Comment: Yes I know. I was simply saying though, that in a more general sense, it would benefit the OP to know the idiomatic way of getting indexes. For times when they _do_ need to know this.

Comment: Sorry, we will just have to agree to disagree. The idiomatic form of `for i in range(len(lista)): x = sum(lista[i])` is `for e in lista: x = sum(e)`. `enumerate()` has it's uses but it's not relevant here.

Comment: Alright. I appreciate you listening then. I can respect that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this?

```
lista = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

print(lista)

def filas(lista):
    summed_list = [sum(i) for i in lista]
    print(summed_list)
filas(lista)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easly, with dot product. This is much faster than any loop.

```
lista = np.float32([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
vet_one = np.ones(len(lista))
vet_sum = lista.dot(vet_one)
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want to do?

```
def filas(lista):
    res=[]
    for elemento in lista:
        x = sum(elemento) # <- change this line.
        res.append(x)
    print(res)
```