# Using map to sum the elements of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering if map can be used at all to sum the elements of a list.

assume `a = [1, 2, 3, 4]`

`list(map(sum, a))` will give an error that `int object is not iterable` because list wants iterables.

`map(sum, a)` is a valid statement but given the object, I do not see an easy way to dereference it.

`[map(sum, a)]` will return an object inside the list

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283689/python-sum-the-values-of-lists-of-list/13283721#13283721) answer states that it should be easy. What am I missing here?

Comment: What's wrong with `sum(a)`? `map` is meant to be used when you want to apply a function element-wise to a list. `sum` takes iterables. Applying `sum` to a single number (as map does) is meaningless.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, nothing, just playing with possibilities.

Comment: Also, the linked answer deals with lists of lists, which is where `map` + `sum` is applicable. Meanwhile, you have a list of numbers.

Comment: 3rd, and most importantly, the error is not generated by calling `list`, it is generated by calling `sum` on a number. Open an interpreter, and type `sum(1)`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ aah, now i see it! Thank you.

Comment: Well, it was a mistake. I just did notice it, so I told. I saw those comments later.

Comment: it is not any hard issue to get offended. Chill :)

Comment: I understand, and I accepted my mistake. And thanks for reminding me. I am not ego filled. But many times people simply get offended, my past two experience, So I thought you also got offended. Thank you. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
x = list(map(sum,a))
```

Is equivalent to

```
x = []
for i in a:
    x.append(sum(i))
```

Sum needs a iterable to apply sum across. If you see the docs syntax goes this way `sum(iterable[, start])`. Since `int` is not an iterable you get that error.

Comment: It is not exactly equivalent because `map` returns a generator.

Comment: @Gino thats for a simple representation for understanding what `sum(int)` does. There is a need for appending data to a empty list or a list comprehension. And map is an iterator function.

Answer (score 14):

[`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) applies a function to every element in the list. Instead, you can use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
sum_a = reduce(lambda x, y:x+y, a)
```

In this case, purely [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) can be used, however, to be more functional, `reduce` is a better option.

Or, in Python3:

```
from functools import reduce
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
sum_a = reduce(lambda x, y:x+y, a)
```

Answer (score 7):

Of course if one just want to sum the elements of a list, he should simply call `sum(list_)`.

Now, comming to your question: `map`, both the Python built-in and the pattern refer to applying a function to a data sequence, and yield another sequence, with a separate result for each element in the initial sequence.

`sum` does not do that - it yields a single result for the whole sequence. That pattern is called `reduce`, and so is the Python ex-built-in to do that. In Python 3, it was "demoted" to the `functools` module, as it is rarely used when compared to the map pattern.

The `sum` built-in itself employs the "reduce" pattern alone - but if you were to explicitly recreate `sum` using the reduce pattern it goes like:

```
from functools import reduce
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
reduce(lambda result, value: result + value, a, 0)
```

The first parameter is a callable that takes the "accumulated result so far", the second value is the sequence of items you want to run reduce at, and the third parameter is the initial value to be passed as the accumulated result. (so,it starts at zero). For a multiplicatory, we could use:

```
reduce(lambda result, value: result * value, a, 1)
```

**update**: Python 3.8 implemented the "multiplicatory" in the standard library as `math.prod`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it purely functionally.

```
from operator import add
from functools import reduce
result = reduce(add, a)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error `int object is not iterable` is not because `list` expects an iterable, but `sum` expected an iterable.
The following code:

```
map(sum , [1,2,3,4])
```

Is somewhat equivalent to:

```
[sum(x) for x in [1,2,3,4]]
```

Executing the last expression yields the same error.

Answer (score 1):

```py
reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, L) #summing all elements of a list L
```

Using map reduce and printing the elapsed time in seconds

```py
import time
from six.moves import reduce
import numpy as np
start=time.time()
L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
result = reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, L)
end=time.time()
print("sum of list L ", L, " is equal to", result)
print("elapsed time is ", end-start, ' seconds')
```

output:

```
sum of list L  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]  is equal to 55
elapsed time is  0.00014519691467285156  seconds
```

using python's build-in **sum** function and elapsed time

```py
start=time.time()
s = sum([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
end=time.time()
print("elapsed time is ", end-start, ' seconds')
```

output:

```
elapsed time is  9.226799011230469e-05  seconds
```

sum is a slightly faster method since 9e-05 is less than 1e-04

Answer (score 0):

Indirectly you can add all the elements of a list using a map function using a global variable like below:

```
# reading the file
with open('numbers.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f]

numbers = [int(line) for line in lines]
all_sum = 0
def add(n):
    global all_sum
    all_sum += n
    return(all_sum)

result = map(add, numbers)
print(list(result)[-1])
```

There is only one number in one line in the text file.