# Converting Sigma Function (sum of numbers) to Lambda

Tags: python

I am trying to convert this sigma function to Lambda :

> Sigma : shorthand notation for the sum of terms that follow a pattern.

```
def sigma(first, last):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(first, last+1):
        sum += i
    return sum
```

I tried at first to see if I can put the first and last number, so I started it with `somme = lambda x,y :`  but I need to for `for-loop` or the `range` instruction.

Comment: Why do you need a lambda? `sum(range(first,last+1))` should be enough

Comment: If you need to involve a lambda, you'd be looking at a *reduce* operation: `reduce(lambda: a, i: a + i, range(first, last + 1), 0)`. But that is silly when there's a builtin `sum`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using map to sum the elements of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47927234/using-map-to-sum-the-elements-of-list)

Comment: See the [duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47927234/using-map-to-sum-the-elements-of-list) which more or less covers this and what deceze suggested. Though using `sum` here is the obvious choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sigma = lambda first,last: sum(range(first,last+1))`

`sigma = lambda first,last: sum([i for i in range(first,last+1)])`

I do not know why do you require to convert sigma to a lambda function. However, if you like to do that for some very specific reasons you can use the abovementioned codes.

Comment: The second version is entirely superfluous and adds nothing over the first except overhead. In general, Python highly discourages this kind of `lambda` declaration, this should be a normal `def`.

Comment: I am completely agree with you. However, they might be needing it for some very specific tasks. Thanks for a comment.