# Python map and sum functions

Tags: python

when I wrote  `map(sum,[1, 2]))`, I have not gotten any errors but as soon as you write `list(map(sum,[1, 2])))` you will get an error. Actually, I know about the error "int is not an iterable" that you will get when you run this code.
But I just want to know why `map(sum,[1, 2]))` not evaluate as like as `list(map(sum,[1, 2])))` code.
Would you please help me out?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47927234/using-map-to-sum-the-elements-of-list   Check for duplicated question before asking

Comment: thanks for your comment! actually, I checked it before. but it did not help me why this happened exactly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using map to sum the elements of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47927234/using-map-to-sum-the-elements-of-list)

Comment: No, it did not. In that post,  just showed that this is happening and no explanation is given for exactly what happens when we get this answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that question. I edited my post to clarify more about what is my problem exactly.

Comment: I think your actual question is addressed by this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37417210/lazy-evaluation-of-map

Comment: Yeah, it is. Thnx:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` returns a *lazy* iterator. Any error that occurs when it tries to produce the next element will only appear once you start consuming the iterator. That is what `list(map(...))` does.

For the error itself:

```
sum([1, 2])  # == 3
```

will work, but

```
map(sum, [1, 2])
```

will try to produce the values

```
sum(1)  # this triggers the error
sum(2)
```

which does not work, as `1` and `2` are not iterables themselves.

You can retrace those two separate steps of creation of the lazy iterator object and its consumption:

```
m = map(sum, [1, 2])  
# is ok: first arg a func, second arg an iterable, the constructor of the Map class is still a happy camper!

s = next(m)  
# not ok: pulling the first element from the iterator
# calls sum(1) and fails expectedly.
# Repeated calls to `next` are what happens under the hood in the 
# list constructor
```

Answer (score 1):

You've written it in a way that `map` applies function `sum` to every element separately, i.e. it would try to call `sum(1)` and then `sum(2)`, which can't be done, because neither `1` or `2` are iterable (they're not list/set/string etc).

Why didn't it throw an error with just `map(sum,[1, 2]))`? Because calling `map` doesn't actually start to do any actions, instead it creates a so called *lazy iterator*, that will start applying actions only when you **ask** for it (e.g. calling `list(map(sum,[1, 2])))` **asks** for iterator to process all the elements, and it starts throwing errors because of what I already said.